# json_normalize: Accessing data from an object in an array

Tags: pandas

I have a large amount of information I need to extract from a JSON "List" to a pandas dataframe.

Consider the following JSON file:

```
{
    "List": [
        {
            "Name": "xml",
            "CreateTime": "2020-11-13T10:44:20",
            "Descriptor": {
                "Location": "some/url",
                ...
            }
            "Permissions": [
                {
                    "Principal": {
                        "Identifier": "ALLOWED_PRINCIPALS"
                    },
                    "Example": [
                        "ALL"
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I am extracting the information from this json to a pandas dataframe with the following python code:

```
for List in response['List']:
    df = pd.json_normalize(response['List'])
    df = df.reindex(columns=['Name','CreateTime','Descriptor.Location','Permissions[Identifier]'])
```

The first three columns populate without an issue but I'm having trouble accessing the data stored in a

- library ({} brackets): for example "Permissions[Identifier]" and
- array ([] brackets): for example "Permissions[Example]".

The other columns populate the dataframe while I just get NULL's for Identifier and Example.
I have also tried specifying: Permissions['Identifier'], but that would be a syntax error in my example.

Second example: An array inside of a nested library

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "TableName": "data",
            "Descriptor": {
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "Name": "category",
                        "Type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "author",
                        "Type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "title",
                        "Type": "string"
                    },
                    ...
```

In this case I'm trying to access the values of the multiple "Name" columns under "Descriptor" -> "Columns"

Using Jonathan Leon's solution for the first part I've tried the following code for this second example:

```
for DatabaseList in db_response['Table']:
    df = pd.json_normalize(db_response['Table'], record_path=['Descriptor.Columns'], 
                        meta=['TableName', ['Descriptor.Columns']])
    df = df.reindex(columns=['TableName','Name'])
```

Defining the record path like that is unfortunately not possible. I have to somehow define a nested record_path to access the data within "Columns".

I will also have to add record_prefix to the json_normalize part since there are multiple "Name" columns.

What would be the correct syntax to access the lib and array data with the python code in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the truncated list you provided, this should get you started. Docs for json_normalize are [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). For multiple layers of lists, you may have loop through and concatenate dataframes.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response['List'], record_path=['Permissions'], meta=['Name', 'CreateTime', ['Descriptor', 'Location']],
                        meta_prefix='', record_prefix='')
df = df.reindex(columns=['Name','CreateTime','Descriptor.Location','Principal.Identifier', 'Example'])
df.rename(columns={'Principal.Identifier':'Permissions.Identifier'})
pd.concat([ df, df['Example'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)
```

output (I modified the Example list to illustrate expanding the values):

```
  Name           CreateTime Descriptor.Location Principal.Identifier      Example    0     1
0  xml  2020-11-13T10:44:20            some/url   ALLOWED_PRINCIPALS  [ALL, SOME]  ALL  SOME
```

Comment: Yep, it works for both cases I noted. Thank you very much for taking the time to write the code for my example.

Comment: Would you mind looking at another case I'm having trouble with?

Comment: @ire glad it worked for you. Post your other question with what you've tried. Best to have multiple people have the opportunity to answer.

Comment: I have added the second part to my main post.

Answer (score 1):

For the second example, this should get you started

```
response = {
    "Table": [
        {
            "TableName": "data",
            "Descriptor": {
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "Name": "category",
                        "Type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "author",
                        "Type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "title",
                        "Type": "string"
                    }]}}]}

cols = response['Table'][0]['Descriptor']['Columns']
df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
df.drop('Type', axis=1, inplace=True)
df['TableName'] = response['Table'][0]['TableName']
```

Comment: It did get me started and I figured out how to get the data I wanted :) Thank you very much